# Syntax error on token "assert", invalid VariableDeclaratorId

Tags: java, assertion

**Here is my code**

```
public class assertion {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int a=11,b=3,i=0;
    double assert=2.4;
    a+=a;
    b+=b;

    if(i!=0) {
        System.out.println("hi");
    } else {
        assert a+b==11:"a+b=11";// stops the exe of the program
        System.out.println(a+b);
    }

  }

  }
```

At **"double assert=2.4;"** statement I'm getting **error** as **"Syntax error on token "assert", invalid VariableDeclarat"**. Please help me out.

Comment: `assert` is a keyword, so can't be used as variable name. Read [THIS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html) for better understanding on variable declaration.

Comment: If you look into your question here in StackOverflow, it is very clear that the `assert` is in blue like `if`, `else` or `double`.

Comment: @ Abhi thanks for reply but i read that assert can be used as identifier in java lanuage specs . Please refer this site :docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/… where see the paragraph below the Compatibility With Existing Programs subheading. I hope you'll reply me

Comment: @BabyboB In this [LINK](http://www.oracle.com/us/technologies/java/assertions-139853.html) search for **Source Compatibility** and read...

Answer (score 4):

`assert` is a key word in Java. You cannot use `assert` that way (as a variable).

See [Programming With Assertions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/assert.html) guide.

See also [Java Language Keywords](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html).

P.S. You can use `assert` as a keyword or as an identifier (using `-source 1.3` with `javac`), but not both.

Comment: @ Alexey thanks for reply but i read that assert can be used as identifier in java lanuage specs . Please refer this site :https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/assert.html   where see the paragraph below the Compatibility With Existing Programs subheading. I hope you'll reply me.

Comment: @BabyboB this is pretty old information. Since JDK 1.5 (including) `assert` cann't be used as a keyword. However at 1.4 using `assert` as a keyword just generates warning. That behavior provides back compatibility with old sources. You always may use flag `-source 1.3` with `javac` to compile your code correctly.

Comment: @ Alexey thanks a lot bro. Can you please help me to understand the paragraph which given under the "Requiring that Assertions are Enabled" in docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/…. where it is given that boolean assertsEnabled = false; assert assertsEnabled = true; But how does it possible to use expressions other than a boolean expression in the assert statement in the given code.

Comment: @BabyboB, you can use in assertions only statements, those return boolean value. In that case `assertsEnabled = true` actually returns the result of assignment, which is the boolean `true`.

Comment: @ Alexey. K. How do you say that "assertsEnabled = true" actually returns the result of assignment ? Will an assignment statement return anything ?since it is not method invocation. It's just assigning, right?

Comment: @BabyboB, assignment operator always returns result of assignment. Try `System.out.println(a = 12)` in your code and you will see

Comment: @ Alexey thanks a lot. I got it.